# covnert european time format to US timeformat withAM/PM

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a string I am trying to display in EST time with AM / PM additions. Somehow it is not working the way I want it to.

I tried this:

```
let item = "2022-02-16T20:08:29"

return item.toLocaleString("en-US", {
    timeZone: "EST"
  });
```

expected output `2/16/2022, 8:08:29 PM`

output I am getting `2022-02-16T20:08:29`

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using a date library for that, such as [dayjs](https://day.js.org/) or [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) since working with native `Date` objects are a hassle, broadly speaking.

Comment: You'll first need to turn that string into a `Date` object… Javascript can't guess that your string is supposed to represent a date.

Comment: I just need to get a string "2022-02-16T22:34:42" into a format of 10:34 PM instead of european 22:34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time you are converting is still a string, to access the method toLocaleString you need to be accessing the Date Object.

The date object accepts a string to parse in the constructor as follows.
If you need to convert timezone, then you will need to add in the timezone parameter.

```
let item = '2022-02-16T20:08:29';

function formatDate(date_string){
  let date = new Date(date_string);
  return date.toLocaleString("en-US");
}

console.log(formatDate(item))
```

Comment: Why *two* calls to `new Date`?!

Comment: thanks that did the trick I wanted. I remove item = new Date() and just used new Date(item).toLocaleString("en-US").

Comment: I missed it, thanks for spotting - updated!

Answer (score 1):

`item` is just a string, when you call `toLocaleString()` on it, the [`Object#toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toLocaleString) method gets called, which just returns the `toString()`.

If you first create a Date object from your `item`, your code works, and the [`Date#toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) method is called:

```js
let item = "2022-02-16T20:08:29"

let usDate = (new Date(item)).toLocaleString("en-US", {
  timeZone: "EST"
});

console.log(usDate)
```

If you just need the time, you can use [`Date#toLocaleTimeString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString):

```js
let item = "2022-02-16T20:08:29"

let usDate = (new Date(item)).toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {
  timeZone: "EST"
});

console.log(usDate)
```

Comment: I did that by return new Date(item).toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: "EST" }); but then instead of 10:34.

What is confusing me when I compare the date it shows on the service page I am querying the data from, for example there it is 10:34 PM, when I convert my 22:34 using EST I get a result of 4:34 PM. Although they say they are using EST timezone

Comment: If you already get the date in the correct time zone, you shouldn't add `timeZone: "EST"`as that will add/subtract from the date object when creating the string

Comment: If you dont add Time zone information to your date string, js will assume it's in GMT

Comment: `{ timeZone: 'EST' }` will format the interpreted date *to* the timezone EST; before that it has already been interpreted as *some other timezone* by `new Date`.

Comment: what would be the way to the this into +UTC ? I tried with "UTC" and "+UTC" but it isnt working